# Can a bluetooth adapter be both master and slave in Android-Arduino connection?

Tags: bluetooth

I successfully connected my android phone to my 8051 MCU with HC-05 bluetooth adapter. I can send data from my android phone but I cannot receive data from the 8051 MCU. I know the program on the MCU is correct since I tested it with my computer. I found that some people said that during bluetooth connection, the slave(the 8051 MCU) cannot send data since it is a slave. Is it true? Thanks a lot.

I took the link below as my reference:
http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php

Comment: From the description, error is not clear so cannot comment on the one side failure but bluetooth adapter can act as either slave or a master at a given time.

Comment: Are you looking for http://www.instructables.com/id/Andruino-A-Simple-2-Way-Bluetooth-based-Android-C/

Comment: Bluetooth can be used for bi-directional communication (send & receive). I can talk and hear using bluetooth headset with mobile phone.